# Recursion not working as expected

Tags: java, android, recursion

I have a code that should get a LinearLayout (with more LinearLayout's inside), and get all the views within them. There are some textviews that have tags, and according to this, it should build 3 strings. The problem is it throws an exception in the first line after the loop.  here's a code sample to explain:

```
private void insertToDB(final DataBaseHelper db, LinearLayout layout, 
                              String subject, String term, String meaning) 
{
    View v1 = null;
    for(int i=0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        try {
            v1 = layout.getChildAt(i);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(v1 instanceof LinearLayout)
        {
            insertToDB(db, ((LinearLayout)v1), subject, term, meaning);
        }
        if (v1.getTag() != null) {
            String val = v1.getTag().toString();
            if (val.equals("subject")) {
                subject = ((TextView)v1).getText().toString();
            }
            else if (val.equals("term")) {
                term+=((TextView)v1).getText().toString()+"$";
            }
            else if (val.equals("meaning")) {
                meaning+=((TextView)v1).getText().toString()+"$";
            }

        }
    }
    term = term.substring(0, term.length()-1);
    meaning = meaning.substring(0, meaning.length()-1);
    Card c = new Card(subject, term, meaning);
    db.Insert(c);
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
06-25 20:27:59.332: D/AndroidRuntime(269): Shutting down VM
06-25 20:27:59.332: W/dalvikvm(269): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)

06-25 20:28:01.551: E/AndroidRuntime(269): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-25 20:28:01.551: E/AndroidRuntime(269): java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException
06-25 20:28:01.551: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1579)
06-25 20:28:01.551: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at com.ronEven.iCards.AddRemove$1.insertToDB(AddRemove.java:78)
06-25 20:28:01.551: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at com.ronEven.iCards.AddRemove$1.insertToDB(AddRemove.java:62)
06-25 20:28:01.551: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at com.ronEven.iCards.AddRemove$1.onClick(AddRemove.java:46)
06-25 20:28:01.551: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
06-25 20:28:01.551: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
06-25 20:28:01.551: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-25 20:28:01.551: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-25 20:28:01.551: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-25 20:28:01.551: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-25 20:28:01.551: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-25 20:28:01.551: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-25 20:28:01.551: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-25 20:28:01.551: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-25 20:28:01.551: E/AndroidRuntime(269):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is the exception being thrown?

Comment: You should post the exception stack trace

Comment: I updated my post. The exception occurs because the method doesn't work as I expect it to work...

Comment: I think an excellent question is why are you taking a substring that is simply the whole string?

Comment: each string is in fact a series of strings saperated by '$'. Every time a string is added, a '$' is added too, so there is one spare '$' in the end..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your String.substring calls after the loop apparently causes that problem because they are trying to extract a String portion from an empty string.

Therefore:

emptyString.length() - 1 = -1

Which is an illegal index within a String.

Comment: Ahhh, +1, beat me to it. Should probably add to your post that he can check it using `if (term.length() > 0) { ... }`.

Comment: Now it's OK, but it is repeating the db.Insert(c) line for several times... how can i make it being performed when the whole recursion is finished?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that in these lines:

```
term = term.substring(0, term.length()-1);
meaning = meaning.substring(0, meaning.length()-1);
```

That you are checking to see that `term.Length() > 0` and that `meaning.Length() > 0`.

Otherwise you could be trying to take the substring with an argument of -1.

Comment: Now it's OK, but it is repeating the db.Insert(c) line for several times... how can i make it being performed when the whole recursion is finished?

Comment: You would have to take the Insert function out of the recursive function and instead add "c" to a global array/list of Cards and then when the recursion is finished, use another function to "Insert" all of the cards into the DataBaseHelper db.

Comment: but I want it to be added only once. I want it to go over all the views within the linearlayout and get the text of every textview. then it should create ONE Card object with the texts...

Comment: Then, instead of adding the Cards to a list/array, declare the subject,term,meaning variables outside the recursive function or make it return those values. Then, after the recursive function is called, use the resulting subject, term and meaning variables to create a card and insert it into the db.